# Efficiency Heuristics for Adding Elements to Lists in Python

Tags: python, performance

Suppose my goal is to add elements to list in python if they pass a conditional. There are many ways to do this and I show some. Would it be possible if you could review each block and describe its performance in context of the other blocks? Additionally, if possible, can you provide some performance heuristics for the task of appending these elements to my lists?

For each of these lists, the output is the same

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

**Block 01**

```
my_list = []
for num in range(10):
     if num < 4:
          my_list.append(num)
```

**Block 02**

```
my_list = [num for num in range(10) if num < 4]
```

**Block 03**

```
cond = lambda num: num < 4
my_list = [num for num in range(10) if cond]
```

**Block 04**

```
my_list = list(filter(lambda num: num < 4, list(range(10))))
```

Comment: Have you met our Lord and Saviour, the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html) module ?

Comment: No, I have not met it unfortunately. I am not new to Python but would like to focus more on testing, performance, and optimization. Are there any unix commands you know where, at the command line, I can get performance metrics? Also, can you provide an example of using timeit in one of the blocks?

Comment: Timeit is a standard library module of Python that does exactly that. And no, I don't have any experience using it myself.

Comment: Here: timeit.timeit('list(filter(lambda num: num < 4, list(range(10))))',number=5000) produces: 0.014093596000009256  AND timeit.timeit('[num for num in range(10) if num < 4]',number=5000) produces: 0.006313477999981387 SO Block 2 is more than 2x faster than Block 4 So you can use it in your code: import timeit, then timeit.timeit('expression',number = number of iterations)

Comment: Feel free to use that to answer your own question. That's perfectly valid.

Comment: Block 3 has a bug. Since functions are always truthy, and you don't actually call the function, you get all numbers in the list. It should be `[num for num in range(10) if cond(num)]`

Comment: Anyways, I'm not sure if this is on-topic here. Comparative reviews are OK, but you need to want to get feedback on any and all aspects of the code(s). Instead you seem to be asking us to give you advice on general best practices (which would be off-topic) and this does not seem to be real code, but rather a generic example (hypothetical code is also off-topic). Asking us to write code for you (in this case the timing code), would also be off-topic.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for pointing this out. I am mainly concerned with each of these _specific_ blocks of code and improving each of their performances but the outcome of which works the fastest will determine which I use most often. I suppose I have written my own timing code.